# sc_site on template standard values

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, templates

When opening the experience editor on the standard values of a template, the sc_site=website parameter is passed in the URL.

In my multisite setup I have different sites specified. The codebase takes this site into account to fetch site specific configuration, hence the page has a lot of errors when it is passed the "website" site as sc_site.

I can work around this by changing the sc_site manually. But I would like to automate this and build some logic to pass the correct sc_site on certain standard values of templates.

Any suggestions which pipeline I could break in to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted an answer to this that might work for you here:

[Dynamic Site Provider Experience Editor Resolves to Website](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/dynamic-site-provider-experience-editor-resolves-to-website)

I updates the Experience Editor Command and Preview Command to set the value of sc_site correctly.